# Starting Appium server programmatically

Tags: java, maven, appium

So i am using below code as a try to start the Appium server automatically but getting the connection refused:connect error.
I am using Maven with Testng

*Logs:*

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest capabilities
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused: connect
>   Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z'
>   System info: host: 'MEL01-ULPT027', ip: '172.24.80.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
>   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$2(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:141)
>       at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source)
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:140)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)

*Code:*

```
public class Startup {


 RemoteWebDriver driver = null;

    public void startAppiumServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {   

        CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
        command.addArgument("/c");

        command.addArgument("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node.exe");  
        command.addArgument("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\lib\\appium.js");  
        command.addArgument("--address", false);  
        command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");  
        command.addArgument("--port", false);  
        command.addArgument("4723");  
        command.addArgument("--full-reset", false);
        command.addArgument("--bootstrap-port",false);
        command.addArgument("4724",false);
        command.addArgument("--selendroid-port",false);
        command.addArgument("8082",false);

        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();  
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();  
        // executor.setExitValue(1);

        InputStream is = new InputStream() {

            public int read() throws IOException {
                return 0;
            }

        };
        executor.getStreamHandler().setProcessOutputStream(is);
        try {
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
            int nRead = is.read();
            if(nRead!=0)
                break;
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

Comment: A few suggestions: Do not use appium.js, use main.js.  Why are you using the last four parameters?  Also, you might want to use 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks ,just changed the way for starting appium. Now i am creating a bat file and using Java Runtime command i am starting appium server. However on other side now i am struggling with the code for shutting down appium server programmatically. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to avoid running Appium from command line, your code won't work on Linux or different OS. So that use AppiumDriverLocalService to start the server.
You can find [here](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/3-ways-to-start-appium-server-from-java/amp/) useful ways to start your server.

Comment: Thanks ,just changed the way for starting appium. Now i am creating a bat file and using Java Runtime command i am starting appium server. However on other side now i am struggling with the code for shutting down appium server programmatically. Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, can you please send the complete code.Could not understand this.Is this needs to be used with Runtime.getRuntime().exec command